# Filling in a CSS Element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a website and wanted the links to substitue only a certain text instead of loading a whole new site because of (overexagerated example) 3 new words.

The body is divided into one CSS Elements and one for the links

```
<body>
<div id="body>
Here is the entire body, inside a css block
</div>
</body>

<a href="home.html" >
    <div id="box">
    <br> Home <br>
    </div>
    </a>
```

Here i have a nice little div element (which intern is the link) however by clicking on the link i would open an entire new website (which would mean loading all elememts on the site again. I want to make it so that only my body loads and all the other things stay ... something similar to frames in html, however i am trying to stay away from frames due to SEO.

Comment: This makes no sense. We need to see a more complete example of what you're trying to do. You definitely do not dynamically edit CSS in order to *add content* to elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be sure about your question cause you didn't post any code but i think you need jquery .text() to get it and modify with simple javascript.

Try looking at this:

[jquery text](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: Thanks, the anwser was very helpful, and i learned something new today =), however i was hoping if it is only possible per java script without using anything additionally. =)

Comment: Jquery is javascript api, it has more sintax but is written in javascript!